# Php Math Equation with variables

Tags: php, mysql

In My PHP Script I Got A=B-C

`$A = $data['B']-$_POST[C];`

i want subtract 50 or any numerical value.

But I want  `A= B-C-50`

so what is the php code for that.

And tell me also that if i want that subtract percentage of that value like

`A = B-C-(B*10)/100 (10% of B)`

Comment: Please attach your following code and what have you tried, then we might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need next code:

```
$A = $data['B'] - $_POST['C'] - 50; //for your first question
$A = $data['B'] - $_POST['C'] - ($data['B']*0.1); //for second question
```